# UI updates slowly with setTimeout() angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, controller

I am using Angularjs and trying to update my ui. Currently I am making use of these methods to update the ui quickly, but I am getting a 2 second delay before ui changes after controller has been updated with new data.

```
 $scope.sub("panel.service.updateData", updateEventData.bind(this));    

    function updateEventData(ngEvent, data) { 
                var errorMessage = "updateEventData() ";

                        this.timeout(():void=> {
                            this.scope.list.myList = [];
                            this.scope.list.myList = data.data;
                        });
                        console.log(errorMessage+data.type);
                        console.log(this.scope.list.myList);          
            }
```

I have also tried:

- safeApply() method wrapping around the changes in my controller as
  well.
- wrapping my data inside another object 'list'
- updating the controller with a $watch()
- updating the controller with sub/pub

I am currently using a sub/pub mechanism to pass data between controllers and services.

I have a console.log() set up right after the call in the controller to show when it was updated with new data, the controller is updated quickly, but my ui doesnt get the changes for about 2 seconds afterwards.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can force Angular to redraw "right now" by calling `controller.$apply()`. In your code I believe it would be:

```
this.timeout(():void=> {
    this.scope.list.myList = [];
    this.scope.list.myList = data.data;
    this.scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: I have used $apply() and the method I know of using it requires you wrap your changes using an anonymous function inside the $apply method. Not running it afterwards. I tried the $apply method which is used my safeApply() method. Yes safeApply() does work most cases, but not this time.